# Unable to unistall python from the system - fatal error during installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall the python from my system. However, I am getting on error each time - 
Setup Failed - Fatal error during installation.

Versions - 3.6.8 and 3.6.0

What I have tried so far - 
Removed the environment variables 
Deleting the python folders from the C:\Users**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\

But nothing is working. 
I need to clean up my system and freshly install only one version.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest repairing instead of installing. Deleting folders from your system would cause issues with the uninstallation process trying to find and delete all python on your system. Your best bet is to repair it to a working state, then delete it so the uninstall program finds everything and deleted everything properly. Don't delete anything on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Python Installer of the version you are trying to uninstall. When you run the setup select Repair from Modify, Repair, Uninstall.

After that you can uninstall whichever Python version you are trying to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

- This error also occurs when installing Python from the Windows Store.
- Check if this resolves your issue --

Start -> Open **'Manage App Execution Aliases'** -> disable all the Python entries before installing.

- After the install, enable the appropriate aliases for python.exe, python3.exe and possible other version-specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, click on `Windows Button > Gear symbol ⚙ (Settings) > System > About (in the right corner)`, then select `Advanced select settings`. A window will pop up, select `Environmental variables`

If you've installed Python with `PATH .bin`, you should delete the Python path. To do so, delete these:

1. `C:\Users\[YOUR_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\`
2. `C:\Users\[YOUR_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\`

Also, in System variables, if you find Python `value`, delete it as well.

After doing above step, go to: `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs`
and delete Python folder. This folder contains all Python versions installations.

After, these above steps, go to `Control Panel > choose Uninstall a program` . Find Python with version number you've installed, right-click on it, choose `Change > Repair`, wait till it reinstalls required files.

Then go and again right-click on `Python Program > Change > Uninstall`